# Can I have same variable definition in different classes in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, oop

Is it possible to have same variable definitions in two different classes.
I just started learning vb.net and I am trying to implement an address validation API, so far the **UPS class** works for tracking details but the **UPSaddress** Doesn't. The only different thing between both classes are the **path** variable and the parameters for the constructors.

```
Public Class UPS
 Private accessKey As String = "0D0F94260Dxxxxx"
 Private userName As String = "xxxxxx"
 Private passWord As String = "xxxxx"
 Private path As String = "https://www.ups.com/ups.app/xml/Track"
 Public xml As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()



 public Sub New(trackNo As String)

    xml = getUPSXMLbyTrackingNumber(trackNo)
 End Sub




Public Function getIdentificationNumber() As String
    Dim idNo As String = getNodeValue(xml, "TrackResponse/Shipment/ShipmentIdentificationNumber")

    Return idNo.Trim
  End Function
End Class
```

This is the other class.

```
Public Class UPSAddress

Private accessKey As String = "0D0F94260Dxxxxx"
Private userName As String = "xxxxxxx"
Private passWord As String = "xxxxxxx"
Private path as String = "https://wwwcie.ups.com/ups.app/xml/XAV"
Public xml As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()

public Sub New(Address As String,City as String,State as String,Zipcode as String)

    xml = getUPSXMLAddressValidation(Address,City,State,Zipcode)

End Sub

end class
```

Is this approach correct? And this is how I call the classes in the VB compiler

```
    Dim trackNo As String = upsTrackNo.Value
    Dim Address as String = upsAddress.value
    Dim City as String = upsCity.value
    Dim State as String = upsState.value
    Dim Zipcode as String = upsZipcode.value

    'This works'
    Dim ups As New UPS(trackNo){
    ..some code

    }

    'Im not sure if this will work'
    Dim upsAddress as new UPSAddress(Address,City,State,Zipcode){
    ...some code 
    }
```

Comment: Well the last one isnt vb, which are you learning?

Comment: Its the vb compiler, sorry I did not mentioned that.

Comment: Ok but the last code is not vb, its c#, if you're not trying to do it in c# then you dont want the c# tag on here.. maybe thats why you're struggling in the last section because its not vb

Comment: Oh okay got it thanks !

Comment: @BugFinder : The last is VB.NET code _with a touch of_ C#. He seems to be missing the `With` keyword.

Comment: @Cesar : Having two similar variable definitions in two different classes is no problem. However they won't be linked.

Comment: Yes you can use these types of declaration if these classes are not linked together ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you would do this with a base class which holds the common variables. Your other classes then inherit this class and provide their own implementation for the path property:

```
Public MustInherit Class UPSBase
    Protected accessKey As String = "0D0F94260Dxxxxx"
    Protected userName As String = "xxxxxx"
    Protected passWord As String = "xxxxx"
    Protected MustOverride ReadOnly Property Path As String
End Class

Public Class UPSAddress
    Inherits UPSBase

    Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property Path As String
        Get
            Return "https://wwwcie.ups.com/ups.app/xml/XAV"
        End Get
    End Property
End Class

Public Class UPS
    Inherits UPSBase

    Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property Path As String
        Get
            Return "https://www.ups.com/ups.app/xml/Track"
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, Thanks!!....so if I want to use the UPSAddress Class in the vb.net compiler? Dim upsAddress as new UPSAddress(Address,City,State,Zipcode) would work??

Comment: Thanks for the help :)